# How do you make a for loop to always print zero in the beginning, without having a zero element as a first element?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, zero

I tried:

```
mylist=[1,2,3]                                                          
for i in mylist:                                            
    time=0                                                         
    time=time+i                                                  
    print(time, end="")
```

and got:

```
123
```

but I want to get:

```
0123
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: `print '0%d' % (time)` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pad the string with leading 0s so it's always a fixed length?

Comment: Why do you want this? Why print the list if you are wanting something different? Would it be better to just insert the 0 onto the front of the list beforehand? Or are you trying to loop starting at 0? If the last case, skip the list altogether and loop through a range(4) or xrange(4).

Comment: Check my solution and give it a go, missunderstood you not wanting just a fixed length but actually printing zero if not present.

Answer (score 4):

One of a number of ways would be to iterate not over your list, but over a new list that includes zero at the beginning, and then your list.  Like so:

```
mylist=[1,2,3]                                            
for i in [0] + mylist:
    print(i, end="")
```

Comment: Doesn't take into account if 0 already exists but it works assume you don't care :) (Seeing how the title vaguely describes "without having zero as a first element)

Comment: Yeah, the reason there are four or five different correctish answers on this post is because the requirements are not clear.  Is handling that case relevant to the problem?  I have no idea.

Comment: Haha, gotta agree with you on this one :P Wild wild west up in here :)

Answer (score 4):

If the input list is not under your control and you neither want to prepend `0` to it nor to build a new concatenated list (e.g. if it is very large), you can use [itertools.chain()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

mylist = [1, 2, 3]                                                         
for i in itertools.chain([0], mylist):
    pass  # Your loop code...
```

Comment: itertools is cool, though it's a bit overkill for the task. +1 anyway

Comment: Same here, overkill but despite the fact it's a neat solution to a oddly described problem.

Comment: Nope, not overkill, who in their right mind wants O(N) concatenation when you have this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned if the zero is not the first element, go with:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
print(('0' * (1 if mylist[0] else 0)) + ''.join(str(x) for x in mylist))
```

This gives you a 0 at the start if 0 is not the first element in mylist :)

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> print(('0' * (1 if mylist[0] else 0)) + ''.join(str(x) for x in mylist))
0123
>>> mylist = [0,1,2,3]
>>> print(('0' * (1 if mylist[0] else 0)) + ''.join(str(x) for x in mylist))
0123
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, looking at the edited code:

```
mylist=[1,2,3]                                                          
for i in mylist:                                            
    time=0                                                         
    time=time+i                                                  
    print(time, end="")
```

Obviously doing `time=0` then `time=time+i` each time through the loop is the same as `time=i`. So, `print(time, end="")` is the same as `print(i, end="")`. So, let's simplify it before trying to fix it:

```
mylist=[1,2,3]
for i in mylist:
    print(i, end="")
```

Now, how do we get it to print a `0` at the start? Well, there is no 0 to get anywhere in the loop, so it pretty much has to come before the loop:

```
mylist=[1,2,3]
print(0, end="")
for i in mylist:
    print(i, end="")
```

Comment: Consider the scenario where mylist is unknown, printing 0 prematurely would result in additional zeroes which might be unwanted :) You're on the right track tho and nice clarifications!

Comment: @Torxed: What makes you think the additional 0 is unwanted? The problem is pretty ambiguous and hard to understand, but it says "always print zero in the beginning", not "add a leading 0 if not present", or "fill to 4 characters with 0", so… this is my guess at what he intended.

Comment: "without having a zero element as a first element" i assumed that it was equal to "print zero if element[0] is not zero" :)

Comment: @Torxed: Well, there's at least three different ways to read the question, and if the OP never tells us which is which, I guess the best thing is just to point out which interpretation each answer answers…

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist=[1,2,3]                                                          
for i in mylist:                                            
    time=0                                                         
    time=time+i                                                  
    print(time, end="")
```

Change this to:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
print('0', end='')
for i in mylist:
    print(str(i), end='')
```

Comment: Consider the scenario where mylist is unknown, printing 0 prematurely would result in additional zeroes which might be unwanted :)